# AngularJS routeProvider not working

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, ngroute, route-provider

EDIT: Solved the problem, seems the '#' character that Angular uses caused the problem. Here are the correct.

Edit after WiRo's answer

(I use grunt for my http-server)

**app.js**

```
require('angular/angular.min');
require('./angular-material.min')
require('angular-route/angular-route.min');
var listController = require('./controllers/listcontroller.js');
var authController = require('./controllers/authcontroller.js');
// Create your app
var app = angular.module("advjavascript", ["ngRoute"]);

app.controller('ListController', listController);  
app.controller('AuthController', authController); 

app.config([
    '$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/auth', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/auth.html',  
            controller: 'AuthController',
            controllerAs: 'auth'
        })
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',  
            controller: 'ListController',
            controllerAs: 'list'
        })
        .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/',
                controller: 'listController',
                controllerAs: 'list'
        });


    }
]);
```

**authcontroller.js**

```
module.exports = function($scope, $routeParams){
var vm = this;           

alert("this"); 

vm.username = $routeParams.username;
    vm.token = $routeParams.token;
    console.log("This token: " + vm.token);
    vm.data = {
        token: vm.token,
        username: vm.username
    };
};
```

**listcontroller.js**

```
module.exports = function($scope, $routeParams){
  var vm = this;  
   vm.data = {
      username: ""
  };

   console.log(vm.data.username);
};
```

**pages/auth.html**

```
    <h1>Logged in!</h1>
    <p>Your username is {{auth.data.username}}</p>
    <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Back to page</a>
```

**pages/home.html**

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<p>Your username is {{list.data.username}}</p>
<a href="http://mahjongmayhem.herokuapp.com/auth/avans?callbackUrl=http://localhost:3000/%23/auth">log in</a>
```

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="advjavascript">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/angular-material.min.css"/>

    <title>AdvJavascript</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div ng-view></div>
   <script src="js/app.js"></script>
 </body>

</html>
```

I have a callback that goes to http://localhost:3000/auth?username=secret&token=secret

It doesn't route to auth.html, heck it doesn't even route to index.html (default page)

Anyone knows what's going on?

Here are the results:

[auth route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5wRG.png)

[normal route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93I31.png)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things to modify (see comments):

**Routing**:

```
app.config([
    '$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/auth', {
            // you used  '/pages/auth.html' which may route to the wrong directory
            templateUrl: 'pages/auth.html',  
            controller: 'authController',
            // add this if you want to use controllerAs as in your example
            controllerAs: 'auth'
        })
        .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
        });


    }
]);
```

**Controller**
Make sure you do not mix using `$scope` and controllerAs:

```
module.exports = function($scope, $routeParams){
    var vm = this;           

    alert("this"); 

    // Changing $scope to vm will bind your variables to the controller, 
    // this is what you need to do when using controllerAs        
    vm.username = $routeParams.username;
        vm.token = $routeParams.token;
        console.log("This token: " + vm.token);
        vm.data = {
            token: vm.token,
            username: vm.username
        };
    };
```

You may want to use `ng-view`:
**Index.html**:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="advjavascript">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/angular-material.min.css"/>

    <title>Home</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div ng-view></div>
 </body>

</html>
```

**auth.html**
The auth.html will be included in the `ng-view div-element` by angularjs as soon as your route changes to `'/auth'`. Angularjs will also automatically assign the `authController` to this view.

```
    <h1>Logged in!</h1>
    <p>Your username is {{auth.data.username}}</p>
    <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Back to page</a>
```

Comment: Can you look at my edits please? I appreciate the help a lot!

Comment: try changing the links in your anchors to ` <a href="#/home>Back to page</a>` and to `<a href="#/auth>login</a>`

Comment: What do you mean with 'anchors' and what do I change them to?

Comment: Change `<a href="http://localhost:3000/">` Back to page </a>`  to `<a href="#/home>Back to page</a>`

Comment: I did it, but it doesn't resolve the routing issues. I get no feedback in my console and there seem to be no result in the html. Also the Alert() in authcontroller is not going off. :(